# How to fix "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Unity.RaycastHit2D when trying to compare tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(playerDetection.position, Vector2.right, sightDistance);
if (hit != null)
{
    Debug.DrawRay(playerDetection.position, Vector2.right * sightDistance, Color.blue);
    if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        animator.SetBool("isChasing", true);
    }
}
```

Unity shows me an error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

at line:

```cs
if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")
```

Comment: Looks like `hit.collider` is `null`. Try `hit.collider?.tag == "Player"`.

Answer (score 2):

[`RaycastHit2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D.html) is a [`struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and will **never** be `null`.

For the reason why this doesn't throw an exception see at the bottom of this answer.

---

From [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)

> This function returns a RaycastHit object with a reference to the Collider that is hit by the ray (the Collider property of the result will be NULL if nothing was hit).

So - as they also show in their example - you rather want to check

```
if(hit.collider != null)
```

or since [`RaycastHit2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-collider.html)

> implements an implicit conversion operator converting to bool which checks this property allowing it to be used as a simple condition check for whether a hit occurred or not.

you can also use

```
if(hit)
```

---

what happens if you use

```
if(hit != null)
```

is the following: The implicit operator converts it to a `bool`.

Now no matter if a `bool` is `true` or `false`, the underlying `System.Object` is **not** `null` for both cases.

That is why you don't get a compiler error but the result is unreliable.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! Now it's working and i know what I did wrong

Comment: Oh that was tricky of Unity with the operator. Ya can hurt people when they think the struct is actually an object.  +1 good sir